# asp.net mvc area not working on iis

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I crated **area**/**modular** **MVC5** application according to this tutorial:
[This](https://medium.com/@info_nishant/how-to-create-a-modular-web-application-in-c-mvc-85d8074a26bc#.nddqzirsz)

it worked  perfectly on local. but i got 404 error, when i deployed project on `iis` and clicked on specified area link.

and i didn't find any solution for that.

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>   Requested URL: /Sale

and this is my action links which are perfectly working on local run:

```
     @Html.ActionLink("Sale","Index","Sale",new { Area="Sale"},null)
```

**edited**:

```
    public class SaleAreaRegistration:AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Sale";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.MapRoute(
            "Sale_default",
            "Sale/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Sale", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "MVCPluggableDemo.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

attention: according to the tutorial which i said in first line. i created my module project in another virtual project in solution(the real path is in area folder of main project like"~/ProjectName/Areas/"). but i think the publisher does't understand it...because i don't see any of my module views in deployed path.

its better to completing my help request by this obvious question:
How to deploy **MVC** project include **areas**, and the **modules** which are in areas folder?

Comment: show `routeconfig.cs` and the related `arearegistration.cs` file

Comment: @Shoe i did it in edit ...

Answer (score 0):

Its simply obvious:

```
Check your page directory. The server cannot locate your the file,
it maybe in different folder.
```

Also try to [Check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: you are right ...the directory is not exist in deployed path but i don,t now why publisher didn't understand it ....because its working on local run. :(

Comment: Make sure all file are include in your deployed folder.

Answer (score 0):

the main Reason of my problem was this:

> VisualStudio doesn't include my Area folder, in publish path..why? i don't know

**Solution:** no solution yet!..but i added my module `dll` inside bin folder manually. and created my areas folder and his modules projects solution(dlls' are not not necessary) in main published solution, manually to ..

finally it worked, but i dont thing is the standard solution

Comment: StackOverflow is about answerable questions. You should thrive to mark ANY question you asked as answered, even the answer is of your own.